# Surface normals still regular in edit mode after displacement map

Tags: normals, displacement

I am trying do perform a displacement map in a conical shape. I created a circle, extruded in Z and resized at the other side. After that, I selected everything and subdivided to have a bunch of small faces. Then, I added a displace modifier and a image texture, so that it becomes like the surface in the top (Object Mode):

[image: Displacement map without "displaced" normals]

The problem is, when I change to Edit Mode I can see that the normals keep as the surface was completely regular, which is not desirabe. I wanted the normals to follow the surface relief, is there a way to do that?

Edit: Accepted answer from Robin Betts, results (I extruded the surface, so that I can have normals on both sides):
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If, in the Displace modifier, (as you could with most other modifiers) you click the little mesh-triangle tool-tipped 'Adjust edit cage to modifier result', you should be able to edit the vertices, and see the normals, of the modified mesh.

Comment: This works, thanks!! I could not upvote this answer because I don't have enough reputation yet...